# .apk file does not open, no error messages

Tags: android, apk

I am building a react native app and when I send the `.apk` file to my phone I can't open it.

In the past it was working normally, but one day it just stopped. The same file works fine on my other phone.

Usually I send the file **via slack**, I open in on the phone, it downloads it and installs it automatically. Right now it does not install it.

Even when I find the `.apk` file in my **Downloads** folder, nothing happens if I tap on it.

All of my usual settings seem correct. When I publish the app to the **Play Store** it downloads and installs it normally.

I know it's a long shot but I'm wondering if anybody experienced a similar problem.

Comment: Slack downloads are broken, or at least they were as of a few weeks ago. Slack is probably the worst way to send yourself an APK, by the way. Google Drive is better if you can't use a cable.

Comment: Using **apk analyser** double the integrity of your apk after receiving it on client side